# Understanding Hex-Rays pseudo code

Tags: hexrays

What is the meaning of the following pseudo-code?:

1. `BYTE1(v2)` or `BYTE1(v2)`
2. `HIBYTE(v2)`

Is there any explanation for those macros? How can I implement those macros in C code?

Answer (score 4):

`BYTE1(v2)` is the second byte of value v2. according to [the reference](https://github.com/nihilus/hexrays_tools/blob/master/code/defs.h) it's Zero-Indexed. defined as:

```
#define BYTEn(x, n)   (*((_BYTE*)&(x)+n))
#define BYTE1(x)   BYTEn(x,  1)         // byte 1 (counting from 0)
```

for example `BYTE1(0x1213141516)` is 0x15. (according to Little Endian Byte Order)

`HIBYTE(v2)` is the higher byte of value v2. defined as:

```
#define HIBYTE(x)   (*((_BYTE*)&(x)+1))
```

for example `HIBYTE(0x1213)` is 0x12. (according to Little Endian Byte Order)

Comment: Note: HIBYTE **used** to mean that, but it has changed (contrary to IDA 7.0 defs.h and minwindef.h) to mean *the highest byte*, e.g., BYTE7 in an __int64.  Not sure when this happened, but somewhere between 7.1 and 7.5.  Not cool IDA.

After C++ conversion, it now looks like this: ```*(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&x)+(sizeof x/sizeof(uint8) - 1))```

Answer (score 1):

Open your IDA installation folder open plugins\defs.h, this file contains all of the macros used by the hexrays decompiler. It can also be found at the github in arman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Important** -- this definition has changed in recent versions of IDA, both in `defs.h` and in the decompiler output.

As of (some version of IDA between 7.1 and 7.5) the meaning of HIBYTE means something different, I guess you would call it the *most significant byte*, or *highest byte*, or *last byte*.

e.g., in an `__int32` it now means `BYTE3`, in an `__int64` it would mean `BYTE7`.

This is contrary to the default windows definition and older versions of IDA.

```
    // minwindef.h
    auto result_win = static_cast<BYTE>(static_cast<uintptr_t>(x) >> 8 & 0xff);

    // ida_defs_70.h
    auto result_ida70 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&x)+1);

    // ida_defs_75.h
    auto result_ida75 = *(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(&x)+(sizeof x/sizeof(uint8) - 1));
```

Make sure that you are using the definition that applies to your version of IDA, which can be found in `defs.h` in your IDA executable's path under `plugins/`